# Using Variance Threshold with normalized variance

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, statistics, variance

We know that zero-variance or low-variance features should be dropped to help with model complexity. However, I have come to learn that comparing variances of features can be difficult. For example:
[image]

The above features all have different medians, different variances, and ranges. Also, higher values in a distribution tend to have bigger variances. So, to make a fair comparison, can we normalize all features by dividing them by their mean, like so:

```
normalized_df = df / df.mean()
```

I have seen this technique in a DataCamp course and it is suggested in the course that after doing a normalization like above, we can choose a lower variance threshold, like 0.005 to make a fair comparison in feature selection. I was wondering if it was correct.

If it is, what kind of threshold should be chosen for normalized features?

Comment: Isn't the "usual" way to center (`df_c = df - df.mean()`) and then scale to unit variance (`df_cv = df_c / df_c.std()`)? Then all features are normally distributed with `µ=0` and `σ=1`, so no feature can numerically *outweigh* another feature?

Comment: * not normally distributed (depends on the data of course) but `µ=0` and `σ=1` at least ^_^

Comment: @StefanB that's what thought at first but doing that means all features will have the same exact variance. In that case, you can't use variance thresholding. Isn't that right?